How to we consume the API which has the body of the raw text format?
I have an API hosted which will be called from an external source to update a record in our system. The curl of the API is below
curl \
  --location \
  --request GET \
  --header 'X-Vymo-Auth-Token: XXXXXXXXXXXXX3s' \
  --header 'auth-key: XXXXXXXXXXXXX3s' \
  --header 'client: abc' \
  --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
  --data 'ABCD|123456789|MSBI0412001668|NA|00000094.00|SBI|22270726|NA|INR|NA|NA|NA|NA|29-05- 201316:08:56|0300|NA|XYZ|NA|NA|NA|NA|BoKDXlJ5j121248|NA|NA|NA|3734835005'
  'http://localhost:3010/update-digital-payment-status'

Now when I am trying to access the data from the path req.body then it is coming as empty. But if I pass the body as json then I am able to access the data from req.body.
Need help how can we get the body when Content-Type is text/plain.

Please [edit] your question to include the code for your Node.js API

It sounds like you'd want to make use of the express.text() middleware which by default handles requests with text/plain bodies.
For example
app.get('/update-digital-payment-status', express.text(), (req, res) => {
  const data = req.body.split('|');

  // ...
});

See https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.text

FYI defining an API that receives a request body via GET is probably not a good idea.
See HTTP GET with request body for a deeper discussion and this answer for reasons why it will never work from a browser.
